# How to set default hotkey for Custom Command?

Tags: c#, wpf, command, hotkeys

I had create my custom command `New`, `Edit` and `Delet`, I'm set this hotkeys in `InputBinding`, but it is very hard-working when I need use my command every time

`Copy` command example, I don't need set hotkey, but it has default hotkey Ctrl+C

How do can I set default hotkey Ctrl+N, Ctrl+E and Ctrl+D for my customer commands?

```
public static class HWCommand
{
    static RoutedUICommand save = new RoutedUICommand("Save", "Save", typeof(HWCommand));
    static RoutedUICommand novo = new RoutedUICommand("Novo", "Novo", typeof(HWCommand));
    static RoutedUICommand deletar = new RoutedUICommand("Deletar", "Deletar", typeof(HWCommand));
    static RoutedUICommand editar = new RoutedUICommand("Editar", "Editar", typeof(HWCommand));

    public static RoutedUICommand Save { get { return save; } }
    public static RoutedUICommand Novo { get { return novo; } }
    public static RoutedUICommand Deletar { get { return deletar; } }
    public static RoutedUICommand Editar { get { return editar; } }
}
```

my CommandBinding

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static hw:HWCommand.Novo}" Executed="NovoCommand_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static hw:HWCommand.Editar}" Executed="EditarCommand_Executed" CanExecute="EditCommand_CanExecuted"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static hw:HWCommand.Deletar}" Executed="DeletarCommand_Executed" CanExecute="DeletarCommand_CanExecuted"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use different constructor for your [`RoutedUICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522919.aspx)

```
RoutedUICommand(String, String, Type, InputGestureCollection)
```

where you can specify `InputGestureCollection` like so:

```
static RoutedUICommand novo = new RoutedUICommand(
                                     "Novo", 
                                     "Novo", 
                                     typeof(HWCommand), 
                                     new InputGestureCollection(
                                         new InputGesture[] { new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control) }
                                     ));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it is working! but... other question... it accept InputGestureCollection, so can I set more than one hotkey for this command?

Comment: Technically you can put whole list of `InputGestures` which includes [`KeyGestures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture.aspx) and, but this I did not try, [`MouseGesture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousegesture.aspx)